# problem: no vertical space in chapter title using koma-class scrbook

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script

I have a problem with the koma-script scrbook class. I want to have a two lines chapter title like:

[image]

I tried:

```
%%% classe de base (KOMA-Script)
\LoadClass{scrbook}                 %% classe report (KOMA-Script)
\KOMAoptions{paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,DIV=12,BCOR=0mm,twoside=off,index=totoc,headings=normal,listof=totoc,headings=twolinechapter}

%%% extensions minimales
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}            %% fontes de caractère
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}     %% format d'encodage
\RequirePackage{lmodern}                %% fontes latin modern
\RequirePackage[frenchb]{babel}     %% typographie française
\RequirePackage[babel]{csquotes}        %% guillemet

\RequirePackage{lipsum}             %% lorem ipsum (exemple)

%%% extensions complémentaires
\RequirePackage{scrhack}    %% macros et en-tête/pied de page personnalisés (KOMA-Script)
\RequirePackage[headsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{headings}
%%% paramètres
\pagestyle{scrheadings}             %% style de page
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\small\sffamily} %% style de numero de page
```

As well as:

```
%%% classe de base (KOMA-Script)
\LoadClass{scrbook}                 %% classe report (KOMA-Script)
\KOMAoptions{paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,DIV=12,BCOR=0mm,twoside=off,index=totoc,headings=normal,listof=totoc,chapterprefix=true}
```

But I always get the result:

[image]

What is wrong in my code?

Regards

Comment: I can't see this behavior.

Comment: You mean that my code is OK but that I have a bug?

Comment: I mean that if I prepare a document with that code as preamble, with `\documentclass` replacing `\LoadClass`, and just `\chapter{Title}` after `\begin{document}` I get “Chapter 1” and “Title” on separate lines. So there must be something else you're not including in your code. Please, try making a minimal example that *does* show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the oringin of the error. That come from the package sectsty who change the headings. (as my style sheet was extremely long, I didn't display it completely, sorry for that). I will check the sectsty documentation. Thank's to egreg

Comment: Note that it is not recommended to use package `sectsty` together with a KOMA-Script class.